# Create videos with loops and breaks

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I would like to create a video that will be used in place of a usual powerpoint presentation. For this I need that the video automatically stops a some predefined points or that some regions are looped until I press "play" on the player. 
With the DVD format this can be done in a very contrived way (correct me if I'm wrong).
Is there a way to produce those videos with Blender? Are there other formats that support these features?

Thank you

Comment: I doubt it.. Blender's video editing capabilities are pretty basic. You are most likely better off using an external program to set up the DVD formatting (using footage from blender or wherever). Note that I have never fiddled with DVD formats before, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, Blender's VSE can only output a single linear video file. Any stop points, or looped sections would need to be provided during playback with the whatever player or app is consuming the video file.

Comment: I think the OP is thinking about menus, chapters, and loop points, which are all [things DVDs are capable of (according to wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_authoring).

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, I was asking exactly that: is it possible to generate DVD "metadata" using blender? Other video formats are welcome.

Comment: @MarcoM If blender doesn't support this (I'd be surprised if it did), you might try one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DVD_authoring_applications#Free_software).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create interactive movie playback using the blender game engine.
The complexity required will vary greatly depending upon the needs of your project.

To provide some ideas, I dug up a couple of tutorials that look at interactive movies and game cut scenes. An understanding of the game engine will be required however.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PV5dAzgtzA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2W_fQayYcA